# Add vertical and horizontal separators between inline elements

Tags: html, css

There are multiple inline elements in one container:

```
<p>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <span>sit</span>
  <span>amet</span>
  <span>consecutetur</span>
</p>
```

What I need is a vertical separator between the elements that are in the same row and a horizontal separator between the lines. How does this work in CSS?

[image: how it should look like]

Comment: I'm not a CSS guru, however I think you might struggle with the dynamic vertical line without altering your html structure somewhat.

Comment: do you have to keep exactly this html?

Comment: No, the HTML can be changed. But containers for each line are not possible as I do not know the width of each word.

Comment: You cannot do what you want with only HTML / CSS because it is not possible to select the nth line in a paragraph, you have to look at javascript (there are plenty of function to get nth-line on google).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I got it. Not beautiful but seems to work.

```
p {
    overflow: hidden;
}

p span {
    margin: -1px 1px 1px -1px;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    border-left: 1px solid green;
    padding: 0.4em;
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATSzr/)

Comment: Bit of a hack, but it's what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

You can apply `border` to your `span` elements to get horizontal separators:

```
p span:not(:first-child){
  border-left:1px solid #000;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7PF/3/)

But you should change your structure to apply vertical separator. Like this :

*HTML* :

```
<p>
   <span>Lorem</span>
   <span>ipsum</span>
   <span>dolor</span>
</p>
<p>
   <span>sit</span>
   <span>amet</span>
   <span>consecutetur</span>
</p>
```

*CSS :*

```
p:not(:first-child){
    border-top:1px solid #000;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7PF/2/)

Comment: Good idea for the horizontal line but impossible for the vertical lines as I do not know the width of the words.

Answer (score 2):

For example, for a such markdown:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="page1.htm">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.htm">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.htm">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just use such css code:

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Try on your own in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PfUX5/)

Comment: This does not work as it adds the separator at the beginning of every line except the first. The horizontal lines are missing.

Comment: @netAction, oh, yeh, didn't see, that you need horizontal line also. Then, you had the answer above.

Answer (score -3):

You can do something like below and also check ***[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gf2G/)***

```
span{
    border-left:1px solid;
    padding-left:5px;

}

.bottom{
        border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```

Comment: This does not work as it adds the separator at the beginning of every line except the first.
Adding a DIV element for every line is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: @netAction What do you mean by following line??

Answer (score -3):

You can try this. I hope this will solve your problem

```
<p>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <hr style="width: 1px; height: 50px; color: #000;"> 
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <hr style="width: 1px; height: 50px; color: #000;"> 
  <span>dolor</span>
  <hr style="width: 1px; height: 50px; color: #000;"> 
  <span>sit</span>
  <hr>
  <span>amet</span>
  <hr style="width: 1px; height: 50px; color: #000;"> 
  <span>consecutetur</span>
</p>
```

Comment: not even close... http://jsfiddle.net/ghLtx/ And adding markup to achieve styling?